# d3 stopPropagation - "mousedown.log"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I am learning d3 and I came across a previous topic discussing `stopPropagation()`. jasondavies posted a reply to the question and an example here https://gist.github.com/jasondavies/3186840.

In this example he uses:

```
    .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
    .on("mousedown.log", log("mousedown circle"))
```

I don't understand the event "mousedown.log" and how it triggered in this example.

Here is the full code from jasondavies's example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  circle { fill: lightgreen; stroke: #000; }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .style("float", "left")
    .attr("width", 480)
    .attr("height", 480)
    .on("mousedown", log("mousedown svg"))
    .on("mouseup", log("mouseup svg"))
    .on("click", log("click svg"));

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 240)
    .attr("cy", 240)
    .attr("r", 200)
    .on("mousedown", function() { d3.event.stopPropagation(); })
    .on("mousedown.log", log("mousedown circle"))
    .on("mouseup", log("mouseup circle"))
    .on("click", log("click circle"))

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("float", "left")

function log(message) {
  return function() {
    div.append("p")
        .text(message)
        .style("background", "#ff0")
      .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .remove();
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's namespacing for events. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on):

> If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new listener is added. To register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and "click.bar". The first part of the type ("click" for example) is used to register the event listener (using element.addEventListener()) and methods are added on the selected elements as __onclick.foo and __onclick.bar. To remove a listener, pass null as the listener. To remove all listeners for a particular event type, pass null as the listener, and .type as the type, e.g. selection.on(".foo", null).

In this particular example, it means that both handlers are called when a `mousedown` event occurs. Without the namespacing, the second handler would overwrite the first.